# Mac Catalyst UIButton Configuration Issues?

Tags: swift, uibutton, mac-catalyst

I currently have my application set to run on **iPad** & **Mac (Mac Catalyst)**, with my interface option set to `Optimize for Mac`, and am having serious difficulty updating the button padding when running **on my Mac**...

---

When I have `Scaled to Match iPad` selected, this is what it looks like:

[image]

When I have `Optimize for Mac`, it then becomes this...

[image]

---

Here is a quick snippet I put together to try isolating a solution. This exact snippet products the above images when toggling the `Mac Catalyst Interface`.

```
var config = button.configuration

config?.imagePadding = 20
config?.titlePadding = 20
config?.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20)
button.configuration = config
button.setNeedsUpdateConfiguration()
button.updateConfiguration()
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a quick test app and used the following button code:

```swift
var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.gray()
cfg.image = UIImage(systemName: "clock")
cfg.title = "Due Orders"
cfg.imagePadding = 20
cfg.contentInsets = .init(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20)
let button = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
}))
```

This gives the following result when run on a Mac using "Scaled to Match iPad":

[image]

and the following when run on a Mac using "Optimize for Mac":

[image]

When optimized for Mac, the button ignores the content insets and the image padding leaving you with a standard Mac button look. But note that there is space between the image and the title.

Your code doesn't show all of your button setup so it isn't clear how you are getting no space between the image and title.

Comment: Is there no way to force a custom spacing?... seems ridiculous to me

Comment: I was surprised that none of the insets/spacing seemed to have any impact for the full Mac version. But I have no experience with a native (AppKit) macOS app so I don't know what NSButton supports.